# SL DVI-D + HDMI = DL DVI-D, Possible?

Tags: hdmi, dvi

Using Intel HD 3000 graphics card, is it possible to combine the bandwidth of a single link DVI-D and HDMI (using an adapter?) and support a monitor with resolution 2560x1600 monitor instead of 2 1920x1200 monitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the reverse:

A single connector with a dual-link DVI port usually drives a single display. 
It is not capable of getting split in two and driving two independent low resolution displays.

You can use extra hardware to clone the signal and drive two monitors (with identical contents on the screen) or you can use extra hardware like the (now older) 
[Matrox dualhead2go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/digital_se/)'s

Both options require extra hardware.

Vice versa, you can not combine two single-link DVI connections into a dual-link DVI connection. Not without using extra hardware. (and I have found none of those during a quick search on the web).

However, assuming such hardware exists:

- You will need some active (high resolution, else why would you need dual-link) convertors. These are unlikely to be cheap.
- Entry level video cards (easily surpassing the performance of a HD3000) are cheap and do come with dual-link DVI.

PS: If you do search the web, do not get confused with the [DMS59](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-59) connector, you can not use that 'reversed' to solve you problem. Even though it looks a lot like DVI.

[image]

Comment: Interesting answer, but you write "you can not combine two single-link DVI connections into a dual-link DVI connection". Why not? Because technically, dual-link DVI are two TDMS channels with the same clock. And, depending on the motherboard, the vendor may opt to use one PLL to drive two digital outputs (e.g. DVI and HDMI), hence the clock should be the same. What would be the reason one couldn't use the two to drive one monitor (especially thinking that under Linux, one could configure the GPU to do what you want).